# Attribute Object Error "Object has no attribute 'message'"

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hi I'm getting the error

```
File "C:\Users\Tom\Documents\bot\cogs\misccoms.py", line 28, in giveRole
    example = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.server.roles,name='Example')
AttributeError: 'Misccoms' object has no attribute 'message'
```

From this line of code

```
 @commands.command(pass_context=True,  no_pm=True)
    async def giveRole(ctx):
        example = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.server.roles,name='Example')
        await self.bot.add_roles(ctx.message.mentions[0], example)
```

The function of this command is supposed to place a role on a member in this case the role is `Example`.

The full code as follows is

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from .utils import checks

class Misccoms:
    """Misccoms"""

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot


#Tool Commands


    @commands.command(pass_context=True,  no_pm=True)
    async def giveRole(ctx):
        example = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.server.roles,name='Example')
        await self.bot.add_roles(ctx.message.mentions[0], example)


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Misccoms(bot))
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: code expects that you have variable `message` in class  `Misccoms` - but you don't have it. Maybe you have to use some other class to define `class Misccoms(some_other_class):`

Comment: I think you are missing a `self` parameter as the first parameter in `giveRole`.  Your code is interpreting `ctx` as an instance of `Misccoms` since it is the first parameter in a method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the fix is to add the 'self' parameter before the 'ctx' parameter like this. I've tested it and it worked for me.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class GiveRole():
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(pass_context=True, no_pm=True)
    async def giveRole(self, ctx):
        example = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.server.roles,name='ExampleRole')
        await self.bot.add_roles(ctx.message.mentions[0], example)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(GiveRole(bot))
```